# How to create break within the option elements

Tags: javascript, html

This is giving me both options - icecream and juice side by side within the select tag. I tried `innerHtml`, `InnerText` and `TextContent`. All of them gives the same result.

```
 var selectTag = document.createElement("select");
 var optionTagOne = document.createElement("option");
 optionTagOne.setAttribute("value", "icecream");
 optionTagOne.innerText = "icecream";

 var optionTagTwo = document.createElement("option");
 optionTagTwo.setAttribute("value", "juice"); 
 optionTagTwo.innerText = "juice";

 optionTagOne.appendChild(optionTagTwo)
 selectTag.appendChild(optionTagOne)
```

Comment: Apart from nesting option elements, you're also setting innerText twice for `optionTagTwo`.

Comment: I corrected that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optionTagOne.appendChild(optionTagTwo)` should be `selectTag.appendChild(optionTagTwo)`. You're creating this:

```
<select>
    <option value="icecream">
        Icecream
        <option value="juice">Juice</option>
    </option>
</select>
```

Kind of cool that it works at all, I didn't expect that.